# How to reach dict variables inside another dict?

Tags: javascript

How I can reach dict variables inside another dict?

If you don't understand then:

```
{
    variable: "I need this variable",
    retrive: function(){
        return this.variable // I can reach this information with "this."
    },
    another_dict: {
        retrive: this.variable // I can't do it here is not find the variable and I need this information
    }
}
```